# VPN Kill Switch with SSH exception

Tags: vpn, routing, firewall, iptables

I am running a FreshTomato Router which is constantly connected as a VPN Client.

To force all internet traffic through the tunnel, I am using this as a kill switch (recommended setup from VPN provider):

`` iptables -I FORWARD -i br0 -o `nvram get wan_iface` -j DROP ``

This is working as intented.

Here is my problem and I can't seem to figure out a solution:

**How do I add an exception for SSH connections on a custom port (2222)?** I don't want these to be filtered out by the kill switch. SSH connections should be allowed to bypass the tunnel.

Thanks
Kai

Comment: What solutions _have_ you tried so far?

Comment: @user1686 - I have basically tried this in many variations ```iptables -I FORWARD 1 -p tcp --dport 2222 -j ACCEPT```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my solution - adding the state rule did the trick. While I understand **WHAT** it does, I don't understand **WHY** it works. Anyway, it works and the kill switch is still in place...

```
iptables -I FORWARD -i br0 -o `nvram get wan_iface` -j DROP
iptables -I FORWARD -p tcp --dport 2222 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```